# Relação 1:N checar data, diferença 6 mês

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net, tsql

Estou desenvolvendo uma procedure SQL Server, que relaciona duas tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde um processo tem N andamentos, preciso retornar os seguintes dados: todos NumeroProcesso que estejam com a coluna `Irrecuperavel(int) = 1` e que a "ultima" data inserida na tabela Andamento para aquele NumeroProcesso `DataAnda(date)` seja `>= 6` meses.

```
SELECT  
       A.NumeroProcesso, MAX(A.DataAnda) 

FROM   Andamento AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN Processo AS P

ON     A.NumeroProcesso = P.NumeroProcesso
WHERE
       (P.Irrecuperavel = 1) AND 
       (DATEDIFF(MONTH, A.DataAnda, GETDATE()) >= 6)

GROUP BY A.NumeroProcesso
```

Minha procedure retorna mas não filtra pela maior data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que está a faltar na sua implementação é filtar após obter a data máxima para cada processo. Poderia fazer isto em duas partes:

1. Identificar a data máxima para cada um dos processos
2. Aplicar o filtro para obter apenas os processos em que a diferença é superior a 6 meses:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM 
(
   SELECT NumeroProcesso, MAX(A.DataAnda) MaxDataAnda
     FROM Processo P
    INNER JOIN Andamentos A
       ON A.NumeroProcesso = P.NumeroProcesso
    WHERE P.Irrecuperavel = 1
) iP
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, iP.MaxDataAnda, GETDATE())) >= 6
```

Uma outra alternativa mais concisa é possível utilizando a cláusula `HAVING` (uma vez que não é possível utilizar o `WHERE` com funções agregação)

```
SELECT A.NumeroProcesso
  FROM Andamento AS A 
 INNER JOIN Processo AS P
    ON A.NumeroProcesso = P.NumeroProcesso
 WHERE P.Irrecuperavel = 1
GROUP BY A.NumeroProcesso 
HAVING MIN(DATEDIFF(MONTH, A.DataAnda, GETDATE())) >= 6
```

Comment: perfeito! obrigado bom trabalho.